# android:ExecutorService:- ExecutorService does not wait for executorService to complete

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, jakarta-ee

I have an `executorService` that does not wait for the `executorService` part to complete and it directly returns the return value without waiting
below is my code: Please see if I am implementing the `executorService` properly and help me correct it if required

```
 public boolean validateForm() {
        flag=true;
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Future f = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("FLAGssssss", "" + flag);
                    checkSourceCode(new BooleanCallBack() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
                            Log.e("RESULT  ISSSSS", "" + result);
                            validateCode = result;
                            Log.e("validateSourceCode  ISSSSS", "" + validateSourceCode(result));
                            if (validateSourceCode(result) == false) {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                            Log.e("FLAG ISSSSS", "" + flag);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            try {
                if (f.get() != null) {
                    flag = true;
                }
                Log.e("FUTURE IS", "" + f.get());

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (!accept_checkbox.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Accept The Terms & Conditions To Proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //        accept_checkbox.requestFocus();
            flag = false;
        }
        if (!validateAddress()) {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (!validatelandmark()) {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (!validateDistrict()) {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (!validatePincode()) {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (!validateFullfillment()) {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (flag) {
            saveData();
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        return flag; //flag is returned even before the executorService above is executed first
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some confusion on what constitutes a callback from being constructed vs. a callback executing.

The following code is creating and submitting a new `Runnable` task, but the `Runnable` is only printing a message and then constructing a `BooleanCallBack`.  I'm not sure exactly what `BooleanCallBack` does, but assuming it really is a callback, the code in the callback will not execute right away.

For simplicity, lets think of the `Runnable` like this:

```
Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sysou("runnable is running");
        checkSourceCode(new BooleanCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
                sysou("callback from the runnable is running");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When you invoke `future.get()`, it waits for the `run()` method to complete execution, which involves constructing the `BooleanCallBack` but not actually running it.  Similar to how constructing a new `Runnable` object does not mean the code in the `run()` method is executed.

So if your code calls `future.get()`, the only thing you can be sure of is that the run() method has completed (i.e. you have gotten the "runnable is running" message).  *NOT* that `BooleanCallBack.onSuccess()` has executed.

If you actually want to wait for the "callback from the runnable is running" bit, then you need to establish a reference to the `BooleanCallBack` so you can check its status.